# Angularjs : how to make the route view immediately show once refresh the page?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

Once you refresh the page in angular route environment,the specific view of that route will be loaded till the page dom has be loaded (after window.onload event).then it will cause a obvious delay that will make user feel uncomfortable.Is there any solution to make the view show immediately before the window.onload event?
Thanks very much.

Comment: might help if you provided a demo that shows what you are talking about

Comment: demo won't be effective unless he has a demo of a huuuge app.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a generic loading screen using ng-cloak until the app is loaded. I can't think of any solution that will show the exact view you need for that page, without being extremely hacky.

docs:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

example: [Creating a splash screen using ng-cloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294917/creating-a-splash-screen-using-ng-cloak)

Comment: i've tried this and it does worked :).but the problem is it will not wait till the controller stuff of that view to complete.cuz i have some outer route change in the controller.

Comment: hey seems i'v solved this problem,i put the outer view change code into resolve object of route,and the ng-cloak will wait till the resolve code finished.but i am wondering if you got any better solution yo :)